# Post запрос ASP.NET web api

Tags: c#, post, angular2, asp.net-web-api

при попытке отправки Post запроса с клиента(Angular2) на сервер ASP.NET web api, в ответе с сервера приходит ошибка

```
{"Message":"Запрошенный ресурс не поддерживает HTTP-метод \"GET\"."}
```

С чем это может быть связано? и как можно решить проблему
Сам код контроллера:

```
using RealAgency.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http.Results;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RealAgency.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers:     "*", methods: "*")]
public class PostAdController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult PostAd( Card data)
    {
        return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Пришли пожалуйста код с вызовом контроллера

Comment: Видимо пришел не `POST` запрос, а `GET`

Comment: Как-то странно , что шлёте Post запрос , а пишет что пришёл Get. Попробуйте поставить [HttpGet("")]  атрибут вместо HttpPost , если вам нужен Get запрос , в противном случае ошибка в том что шлёте Get запрос с клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Метод, который Вы описали в коде принимает только Post запросы, поэтому и возникает ошибка. Для того, чтобы это исправить добавьте метод с атрибутом [HttpGet] или поменяйте атрибут у текущего метода.

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости вы отправляете GET-запрос,в то время как контроллер поддерживает только POST-запросы. Добавте метод с атрибутом [HttpGet], этот метод будет срабатывать при получении GET-запроса.

Гайд по запросам Asp.Net можно найти на Metanit, к примеру вот этот:
https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/5.2.php

Или вот этот:
https://metanit.com/web/angular2/6.4.php